# Browser not opening when exporting HTML from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Org-mode can export as HTML and open on a browser with <kbd>C-c C-e h o</kbd> (`org-export-dispatch`), but the problem is that the generated html file opens in a buffer inside emacs. There is no error in the message buffer, either. How can I make it work?

When I click a link inside org-mode, the browser opens correctly.

I'm running org-mode 8.2.10, emacs 24.3.1 on manjaro linux 0.8.10. I checked preferred applications in KDE and it points web browsing to firefox.

Comment: Have you tried `C-c C-e b`?

Comment: There is no option `b` after C-c C-e. It gives `Invalid key`

Comment: I apologize. How about`M-x org-export-as-html-and-open`?

Comment: The message after that command is: `org-html-do-expand: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-html-special-string-regexps`

Comment: Okay, that is really weird. The last thing I can tell you to try is: `C-c C-e h h` But, I am not 100% sure that will work.

Comment: With that it writes the html file without opening it anywhere. Thanks for trying, @King.

Comment: I got the same issue. Emacs 27.0.50; org 9.1 then updated to 9.2. I even added snippets by skizo & chen bin still dosent work.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem after a new installation of ArchLinux with XFCE.

Although I didn't manage to understand the problem, a workaround was to configure 'org-file-apps' as described in the FAQ :

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#external-application-launched-to-open-file-link

in my .emacs.d/init.el, I have now :

```
 '(org-file-apps
    (quote
      ((auto-mode . emacs)
      ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
      ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "/usr/bin/firefox %s")
      ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq browse-url-generic-program
      (cond
       ((eq window-system 'mac) "open") ; mac
       ((or (eq system-type 'gnu/linux) (eq system-type 'linux)) ; linux
        (executable-find "firefox"))
       ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emacs --version 
GNU Emacs 25.1.1
```

It works for me:

```
(setq org-file-apps
    (quote
        ((auto-mode . emacs)
        ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
        ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "/usr/bin/firefox %s")
        ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))))
```

REF from answer of @skizo

Answer (score 0):

As documented on [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#external-application-launched-to-open-file-link) (and mentioned in other answers), org-mode uses`org-file-apps` to determine how to open files.  Moreover, `org-file-apps` can call emacs functions instead of specifying external applications.  Especially for opening stuff in the web-browser, emacs ships with the `browse-url`  package.  This package provides a lot of functions to call a lot of different browsers (most of them are not really used anymore), and `M-x customize-group` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `browse-url` can help to give an overview.
When `browse-url` is configured correctly, then the function `browse-url` will open a new browser (or a tab in an already running browser).  This can be leveraged in `org-file-apps`:

```lisp
(setq org-file-apps
    (quote
        (
          ("\\.x?html?\\'" . browse-url)
        )
    )
)
```

This configuration is more portable then specifying exact paths, and it also allows to have a different entry in the `.mailcap`, which org-mode normally uses if nothing is defined in `org-file-apps`.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you have a mixed installation of org-mode. See the FAQ here:

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#mixed-install

When this has happened to me what I have done is (assuming you install via ELPA):

1. uninstall org-mode
2. quit emacs
3. restart emacs using `emacs -q`
4. manually add `("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")` to `package-archives` and run `(package-initialize)` `
5. install org-mode
6. restart emacs

Hope that helps.

Comment: It didn't work. I also erased my .emacs folder and started from scratch (like emacs -q, I guess), only installing org-mode (which appears to be today's version) as you suggest, and the file keeps opening in a buffer. `org-version` gives good result (as in your link). Bad luck.

Comment: Now, if I try @King suggestion: `org-export-as-html-and-open`, the answer is `No match`, so it seems that function is not well installed.

Comment: Export and open uses `org-open-file`, which uses the variable `org-file-apps`. Perhaps you have something strange in that variable. `org-export-as-html-and-open` is not a function in recent org mode versions.